# Search Inside Table Type of Records

Tags: sql, oracle, types, plsql, oracle11g

I have the below types

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD" IS OBJECT  (
  CharacteristicID              NUMBER,
  NewValue              VARCHAR2(200 Char),
  NewValueName      VARCHAR2(200 Char)
);


 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_TABLE" IS 
  TABLE OF CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD;
```

and the below Procedure

```
DECLARE 

characteristic CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_TABLE:=CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_TABLE(

      CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD(2,'ZIKA','ZIKA'),
      CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD(3,'MIGO','MIGO'),
      CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD(4,'ZAG','ZAG')

);

char_record CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD;

BEGIN


END;
```

and i need to select from characteristic record with CharacteristicID = 3 into the char_record variable

Comment: The `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_TABLE" IS 
  TABLE OF CLONE_PRODUCT_RECORD;` does not compile. I think you meant `as table of clone_product_char_record`?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare 
characteristic CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_TABLE:=CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_TABLE(
      CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD(2,'ZIKA','ZIKA'),
      CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD(3,'MIGO','MIGO'),
      CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD(4,'ZAG','ZAG')
);
char_record CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD;
BEGIN
  for i in 1 .. characteristic.count loop
      if characteristic(i).characteristicID = 3 then
         char_record := characteristic(i);
         exit;
      end if;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(char_record.newValue);
  dbms_output.put_line(char_record.newValueName);
END;
/
```

Alternatively, you might want to try

```
declare 
characteristic CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_TABLE:=CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_TABLE(
      CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD(2,'ZIKA','ZIKA'),
      CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD(3,'MIGO','MIGO'),
      CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD(4,'ZAG','ZAG')
);
char_record CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD;
BEGIN

  select CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD(characteristicID, newvalue, newvaluename)
    into char_record from
   table(characteristic)
   where
      characteristicID = 3;

  dbms_output.put_line(char_record.newValue);
  dbms_output.put_line(char_record.newValueName);
END;
/
```